# How to add a module programmatically in Wildfly?

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

In Wildfly-CLI `jboss-cli.sh`it is possible to add a module like this

```
module add --name=org.postgres
           --resources=postgresql-42.2.5.jar
           --dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api
```

This adds the file `postgresql-42.2.5.jar` and creates `module.xml` with the following structure in `/modules/org/postgres/main`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.postgres">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="postgresql-42.5.1.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

How can this be done programmatically with `ModelControllerClient` (available in `org.wildfly.core:wildfly-controller-client:19.0.1.Final`)?

```
ModelControllerClient client = ModelControllerClient.Factory.create(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9990);
```

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done with the `ModelControllerClient`. The `module` command is a high level CLI command and not what is referred to as an operation.

You could launch a CLI process and send the command. The other option would be to copy the JAR and create the `module.xml` programmatically.